# Are the values of sys.argv strings? I need lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, shell, command-line

I have a VBA script that runs the following in the command prompt:

```
D:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.10.3\python-2.7.10.amd64\python.exe D:\GITREPOS\PythonInertia\govlauncher.py [1.1304891,0.5510243,-10.5614766,64.1317974,9483.8000655,9309.4488664,906.3935329,-25.6269843,198.8456995,167.5522187] [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] On 3.8 1800 1900 88.5 -13.64 10 61 16 39.465 True
```

That runs a python file called govlaunch.py that takes a bunch of arguments that I am parsing by using sys.argv[1] or sys.argv[n].

Strangly, sys.argv[1] shows up as `[1.1304891,0.5510243,-10.5614766,64.1317974,9483.8000655,9309.4488664,906.3935329,-25.6269843,198.8456995,167.5522187]` which is exactly what I want... but it's a string instead of a list like I expected.

Are all of the values sys.argv[0] through sys.argv[14] going to be string types?  How do I go about changing them to what I need?

Comment: You can parse a string as a literal using [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

Comment: With that much data you’re passing, you’re better off storing it in a structured file and loading from that instead. Otherwise you will sooner or later run into issues where the executing shell is partially messing with your input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can parse a string as a literal using [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

```
import ast
s = "[1.1304891,0.5510243,-10.5614766,64.1317974,9483.8000655,9309.4488664,906.3935329,-25.6269843,198.8456995,167.5522187]"
x = ast.literal_eval(s)
print (x)
print (type(x))
```

Output:

```
[1.1304891, 0.5510243, -10.5614766, 64.1317974, 9483.8000655, 9309.4488664, 906.3935329, -25.6269843, 198.8456995, 167.5522187]
<type 'list'>
```

Comment: I like this one if you know you gotta pass a list for that first arg

Comment: Wow, it worked just like you said it would!  I didn't expect the args to be strings, but now that I know I can handle it thanks to you!  I really apprecieate you taking the time to help out with a dumb question!

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

Running;

```
import sys
for arg in sys.argv:
    print(type(arg))
```

With;

```
python debug.py foo "bar" 123 False 1.23
```

Outputs the following:

```
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
```

If you want to parse them use a parser, such as `argparse`.

Answer (score 1):

You can separate strings by comma using split() function which returns a list

Answer (score 0):

See the following script:

syspython.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

print(sys.argv)
```

This causes:

```
cchilders:/tmp 
$ python syspython.py one two three
['syspython.py', 'one', 'two', 'three']
```

I would pass these args like:

```
D:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.10.3\python-2.7.10.amd64\python.exe D:\GITREPOS\PythonInertia\govlauncher.py 1.1304891 0.5510243 -10.5614766 64.1317974 9483
```

Just separate with a space, or quote if the arg has spaces like "A book title should be quoted"

As stated below, you can also just split them if you have to:

```
In [1]: x = "[1234,645,44,777]"

# get ride of [ and ]
In [2]: x = x.replace('[', '').replace(']', '')

In [3]: number_list = x.split(',')

In [4]: number_list
Out[5]: ['1234', '645', '44', '777']
```

Here is a nice function to convert your items of argument 1:

```
def stringlist_to_real_list(input_string):
    clean_input = input_string.replace('[', '').replace(']', '')
    return clean_input.split(',')
```

Using it:

```
In [1]: x = "[23,644,777,444,333]"

In [2]: def stringlist_to_real_list(input_string):
   ...:     clean_input = input_string.replace('[', '').replace(']', '')
   ...:     return clean_input.split(',')
   ...: 

In [3]: stringlist_to_real_list(x)
Out[3]: ['23', '644', '777', '444', '333']
```

So now in your script do like:

```
these_numbers_as_list = stringlist_to_real_list(sys.argv[1])
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice!  Unfortunately I can not change the way the args are passed in... not yet anyway.  So I just have to deal with them as it.  But I did completely forget about the split method, I will give that a go!

Comment: The example above is completed, I just threw the lines in function. Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

Don't read from `sys.argv` directly, use a command parser e.g. [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html). This allows to easily pass and cast multiple types; you won't need to manually cast the different strings to type you want, only specify what type the argument should be coerced to when defining the argument.

You could pass a list of ints as argument, by adding it as an argument and specifying the contained type:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--list', nargs='+', type=int)
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice, can I ask why you shouldn't read from sys.argv directly?

Comment: @KeyboardBandit Sure, you can, but with multiple arguments, a parser works better.

Answer (score 0):

Can do slicing then split:

```
s = "[1.1304891,0.5510243,-10.5614766,64.1317974,9483.8000655,9309.4488664,906.3935329,-25.6269843,198.8456995,167.5522187]"
print(s[1:-1].split(','))
```

Output:

```
['1.1304891', '0.5510243', '-10.5614766', '64.1317974', '9483.8000655', '9309.4488664', '906.3935329', '-25.6269843', '198.8456995', '167.5522187']
```

If want list of floats, do:

```
print(list(map(float,s[1:-1].split(','))))
```

Output:

```
[1.1304891, 0.5510243, -10.5614766, 64.1317974, 9483.8000655, 9309.4488664, 906.3935329, -25.6269843, 198.8456995, 167.5522187]
```